# "Uncaught TypeError: d.methods.nl is not a function" on release build

Tags: clojurescript

I call transactions on Ethereum from ClojureScript. On dev build it works fine, but on release build I always receive this kind of errors:

`Uncaught TypeError: d.methods.nl is not a function`
or
`Uncaught TypeError: b.methods.pl is not a function`
etc.

I found that only one transaction call works and I see only one difference there from others: is does not have arguments.

Here is an example of the code which produces the error message (in the send method):

```
(defn end-staking [vampire-address graph-stake-id rewards-token-decimals]
  (let [vampire (h/get-vampire-instance vampire-address)
        account @(rf/subscribe [::web3-subs/web3-account])
        stake-id (subs graph-stake-id 43)
        step (get-in @values [graph-stake-id :step])]
    (-> (.send
          (.endStaking (.-methods vampire)
            stake-id)
          #js {:from account
               :gasLimit "5000000"})
        (.then (fn [receipt]
                 (js/console.log "receipt end-staking" receipt)))
        (.catch (fn [error]
                  (h/hadle-transaction-error error))))))
```

And here is the code which works:

```
(defn close [vampire-address coffin-address]
  (let [coffin (h/get-coffin-instance coffin-address)
        account @(rf/subscribe [::web3-subs/web3-account])]
    (-> (.send
          (.close (.-methods coffin))
          #js {:from account})
        (.then (fn [receipt]
                 (js/console.log "receipt close" receipt)))
        (.catch (fn [error]
                  (h/hadle-transaction-error error))))))
```

Comment: Those error may or may not relate to the chosen optimization and missing externs.  What optimization do you use for your release build? Do the involved libraries have properly defined extern? Or is "endStaking" something dynamic and would you have to call that indirectly so the compiler does not see it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am a newbie in clojure and I don't know where to see the optimization, I don't see something looking like optimization in my project.clj. "endStaking" is a function in an Ethereum contract, so its implementation is not in js.